# Fantasy book about vampires. Read before 1999. The vampires get stronger when getting older

Tags: story-identification

One very old vampire was mentioned that was in consequence very strong but (maybe) less intelligent and more like an animal (beast like).
I believe the very old vampires where practically invisible (undetectable) even for other (younger) vampires.

EDIT: Sorry I do not remember many more details. It was in german (and I just assumed the original must have been in english). It was a paperback version from a library in germany.

Comment: Language? Country? Paperback/hardback? This question is exceptionally sparse on details. Please add whatever you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's an extremely common premise for vampires in fiction, that increasing age also increases their power. As well as Donald's questions, I suggest also providing when you read it. What did the vampires do plot-wise? Were there other characters?

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of Barbara Hamblys novels, Immortal Blood (aka Those Who Hunt the Night) and Travelling with the Dead, set in the early 1900s.

They're actually a good read; vampires don't have morals or qualms and (mostly) look upon humans as playthings before killing them.

*Edit:* I've just found out she added 3 more to the series over the last few years, making 5 in total.